# seek function doesn't work to update a file in a specific position - python

Tags: python, file, seek

I'm actually working on a project to send file using UDP, and since this protocol is not reliable I added some information on each packet which is the index of the data. So I can write the received data in the correct order.
I have problems to write bytes in a specific position in a file

this is the part of my code that handle writing new data :

```
    while i < packet_num:
    buf,address = recieve_packet(s,data_size+10)
    i += 1
    if buf:
        print(buf)
        index = int(buf[0:10].decode())
        data = buf[10:]
        f.seek(seek_pointer + index*data_size,0)
        f.write(data)
        list_index.append(index)
```

in this case the seek function has no effect and the data is just appended to the file. I'm using "a+b" mode to open the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_seek.htm),

> Note that if the file is opened for appending using either 'a' or 'a+', any seek() operations will be undone at the next write.

"a" mode `write` operations append to the end of the file. What `seek` does is it sets the write/read pointer to a specific location in the file.

Therefore, when a `write` is called, it will write to the end of file, regardless of the read/write pointer.

However, because you've opened the file in `a+b`, you would be able to seek to a specific location and `read` it.

Comment: yes exactly It worked when I opened the file using "wb" but I need "ab" because I send the file part by part (in oder to handle huge files) is there any solution to this?

Comment: You can first open the existing file with `r` mode, and get the content. After that, you can create the file again with `w` mode and write the existing comment, and `seek` and add the new content.

Comment: @RS Halim But beware, you can run into memory error if you're working with large files.

Comment: yes, the memory is a problem because I want to send files up to 1Go

Answer (score 2):

If you open using 'append' mode, all writes go to the end of the file.  If ypu are already keeping track of where received data, then opening in `w+b` mode is all you need to do.

`wb` creates (or empties) the file, and allows writing (in binary, rather than text mode). `w+b` Does the same, but allows reading as well. If you want to open an existing file without truncating it, mode `r+b` will allow both reading and writing, while preserving the existing data (again, the `b` is for binary mode, which I expect is correct for your uses).

Comment: is the mode "w+b" works the same as "wb" because I want to update the file, I don't want to lose the old data..