# Python seek() not shifting pointer to right place

Tags: python, readline, seek, tell

I was trying out the following python seek()/tell() function.
"input.txt" is a text file containing 6 letters, one per row:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

```
text = " " 
with open("input.txt", "r+") as f:   
  while text!="":
    text = f.readline()
    fp = f.tell()
    if text == 'b\n':
      print("writing at position", fp)
      f.seek(fp)
      f.write("-")
```

I was expecting the letter "c" to be overwritten as "-" but instead I got the dash appended like this although the print says "writing at position 4":

```
a
b
c
d
e
f-
```

The output is correct when I swop the readline() and the tell() ("b" will be replaced by"-"):

```
text = " "
with open("input.txt", "r+") as f:
  while text!="":
    fp = f.tell()           # these 2 lines
    text = f.readline()     # are swopped
    if text == 'b\n':
      print("writing at position", fp)
      f.seek(fp)
      f.write("-")
```

Can help to explain why the former case doesn't work? Thank you!

Comment: [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43567948/seek-function-doesnt-work-to-update-a-file-in-a-specific-position-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to `flush()` the buffer to disk, because `write` is happening in the buffer in memory not the actual file on the disk.

In the second scenario, before `readline()` you are calling `f.tell()` which is actually flushing the buffer to disk.

```py
text = " " 
with open("input.txt", "r+") as f:   
  while text!="":
    text = f.readline()
    fp = f.tell()
    if text == 'b\n':
      print("writing at position", fp)
      f.seek(fp)
      f.write("-")
      f.flush() #------------->
```

Comment: using "rb+" works too. but you need to change the strings for byte-like arrays

Comment: Thanks a million! Adding the flush() works.