# How to insert data in a file at a specific position?

Tags: python

A file 'webiste.txt' contains text:

```
welcome to geeksforgeeks
```

Python code:

```
f  =  open('website.txt', 'a')
f.seek(11)
f.write("Python")
f.close()
```

desired out: `welcome to python geeksforgeeks`

real output: `welcome to geeksforgeekspython`

when I am running this code in 'a' mode the data gets appended at the last position not at 11th position.
In 'w' mode the data gets entered at position 11th but rest of the data overwritten.

How can we add python at 11th index without overwriting?

Comment: ```open('website.txt','a+')``` Open file in ```a+```?

Comment: I think this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43567948/seek-function-doesnt-work-to-update-a-file-in-a-specific-position-python

Comment: what you are expecting is that when you will write at 11 pos, other text from 11 to end will shift automatically, I don't think there is a method for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert line at middle of file with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507230/insert-line-at-middle-of-file-with-python)

Comment: @Tomerikoo the answer you suggest not working. inserting python where I want to append

Comment: You only have one one line. Read it, change it, write it back...

Answer (score 1):

First open with 'r' method to read content and then use 'w' to rewrite the content and the following code may help :)

```py
with open('website.txt','r') as f:
    content = f.read()
with open('website.txt','w') as f:   
    f.write(content[:11] + "Python" + content[11:])
```